# static keyword after return type

Tags: c++

When I use the keyword `static` with a class member I usually put it before the return type in this way:

```
class Problem {
public:
    static void solve() {}
}
```

I just noticed on VS2010 it works the same inverting it with the return type:

```
class Problem {
public:
    void static solve() {}
}
```

What does the standard say about this? Has this any other implications I should be aware of, or is it exactly the same?

Comment: It is exactly the same but I'm too lazy to get a standard quote

Comment: I believe it is 7.1-p1, and 7.1.1-p1,5. The second of these is the definition of the _decl-specifier-seq_ sequence that allows one storage class per decl (by production from _storage-class-specifier_), but can appear either before or after the type. (not the greatest dissector of specs, but I think that is correct). I could try and slap it into an answer but the answer-editor is really lousy at displaying grammar productions (any hints on a good way to to this are appreciated, btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the various components of the *decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* (ISO/IEC 14882:2011, §7 Declarations) is largely arbitrary.  In particular, storage classes (such as 'static') can be mixed in with the type information, though having the storage class other than first is marked obsolescent in the C standard (but not, as far as I can see, in the C++ standard).